# remove the X axis on a bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, bar-chart, dc.js

[image: This Is what it looks like when I inspect the element][image: How The Graph looks Right Now]
So I am trying to make a Bar Chart with only the labels and no physical line for the X axis. I already managed to remove the y axis by making the left margin -1, but I want to keep the labels that are generated for the X axis.

I have already managed to do this by inspecting my web page and finding the x axis object and changing it from `<path class="domain" d="M1,6V0H391.5V6" style="domain.height: 0;"></path>` to `<path class="domain" d="M,6V0H391.5V6" style="domain.height: 0;"></path>`, which removes the line.

How would I do this using CSS, HTML, or JS?

Comment: is Jquery allowed in the answer?

Comment: Is the y-axis also of class `domain`?

Comment: yes Jquery is allowed and yes, but I have already removed the Y axis by making the left margin -1, and I could do the same with my x Axis, but I want to keep the labels that are generated on the x Axis.

Comment: While you may not be able to see the y-axis, the tag is still there. Is the `<path>` tag for the y-axis in the same class called `domain`, just like the x-axis? Perhaps you can just show us the whole markup for the axes.

Comment: yes, both the x and y axes are called domain.

Comment: Yeah, so I added what it looks like when I inspect and I could just hide the x Axis, but i want to keep all those tick values. But If i change that d value of domain it stops displaying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If jquery is allowed, and if only the `<path>` elements have the class `domain`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.domain').css("display","none");
});
```

If other elements are part of the `domain` class, you can single out the `<path>` elements in `domain` by doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('path.domain').css("display","none");
});
```

This effectively disables the display of the y-axis and x-axis, so no need to set the left margin negative.

Comment: Cool, Thanks! It at first didn't work, but when I added `$('.domain').css("display","none");` right after I displayed the graph it worked.

Comment: That probably means that Bar Chart has it's own function kind of like `.ready()` that jQ was competing with (and losing to in terms of going last).

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, you can simply add:

```
.domain{
    display: none;
}
```

Put the above rule in an external CSS document and add a  tag to the head of the HTML document.

If you don't know how to do that, check out this link: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

This is the simplest solution, if for some reason you need JavaScript, here is the solution in pure JavaScript.

First, add this rule to the external CSS file from above:

```
.display-none{
    display: none;
}
```

Then, in your JS file, add this:

```
var domainPaths = document.querySelectorAll("path.domain");

for(var i=0;i<domainPaths.length;i++){
    domainPaths[i].classList.add("display-none");
}
```

This will hide both the x and y axes.

It may seem complicated now, but learning pure JS will serve you well in the future.